# Atributo sem repetição (unique) com Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

Estou criando um modelo com dois atributos que não podem se repetir, um `GUID` e uma `string`.

Para tornar a `string` (*não é a chave primária* - *a chave primária é o* `GUID`) um campo `unique` devo usar `HasIndex(x => x.Atributo).IsUnique();`?

Se não, qual a forma de fazer?

Comment: Qual versão do EF você está usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que você esteja usando ´Entity Framework 6`, você teria duas opções.

"Fluent Api", que seria o exemplo de sua pergunta. Ou seja, sim você pode e ao meu ver deve criar uma `Unique Key`, como no seu exemplo:

```
HasIndex(x=>x.Atributo).IsUnique()
```

A segunda forma seria Data Annotation Atribute, é uma opção mas eu não gosto pois trabalho com classes "POCO", e esses atributos polouem o código. Mas ficaria assim.

Imaginando que sua propriedade que se chame X

```
[Index( "INDEX_x", IsUnique=true )]
public string x {get;set;}
```

Edidanto a resposta para informar que a solução também funciona para EF Core.

Comment: Blz! Obrigado Rodrigo!!!

Comment: Caso a resposta te atendeu, não esquece de aceitar-la, clicando no V.

Comment: Você poderia completar a sua resposta dizendo que a solução serve para Entity Framework 6 e Core: vide link: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/indexes